# Performance impact on unused require in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I have been wondering if is there any impact on performance in Node.js when including multiple packages using `require()` and not using them anymore? I mean the situation when I, for example, require `underscorejs` and not touch it anymore:

`var _ = require('underscore');`

Doing so in C++ (unused includes) increases the compilation time. But since in JavaScript there is no compilation, is this any harmful? Is the required module loaded when I run the file or only when I use any function from that module?

Comment: Since there is no compilation, there is no way for the JavaScript engine to know that it's not used. It will load the file in memory whether you use it or not, much like if you include a script tag in HTML and never use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An unused `require` will impact your application's startup performance a bit, as well as increase its memory footprint.

The required module is loaded whether or not you later reference the module, so it's worth removing if you're not actually using the module.